# StringBuilder outputting according to index?

Tags: java, tostring, stringbuilder

If first input was "Dog", second was "Wolf", and third was "Cat". The result would be the following:

```
Dog | Wolf | Wolf | Cat | Cat | Cat |
```

Is my forloop causing this to iterate too often?

```
public class LabTextManipulation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> parks = new ArrayList<String>();
        String enteredPark;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean stop = true;
        while (stop == true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your favorite National Park or Done to stop: ");
            enteredPark = input.nextLine();
            if (!"Done".equalsIgnoreCase(enteredPark)) {
                parks.add(new String(enteredPark));
                for (int i = 0; i < parks.size(); i++) {
                    sb.append(enteredPark + " | ");
                }//end for
            } else {
                stop = false;
            }
        }

        String nationalParks = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(nationalParks);
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
" Dog | Wolf | Cat |"
```

Actual:

```
" Dog | Wolf | Wolf | Cat | Cat | Cat |"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is causing the problem

```
for(int i = 0;i < parks.size(); i++ ) {
    sb.append(enteredPark + " | ");
}
```

every single time you are adding new string to the `parks` you are incrementing count of added duplicated values to the sb in the next iteration - I believe you should not use loop at all just

```
if(!"Done".equalsIgnoreCase(enteredPark)) {
    parks.add(enteredPark); // also don't create new String here
    sb.append(enteredPark + " | ");
}
```

Comment: That was it the whole time thanks, no need to have the forloop at all. Thanks! @m.antkowicz